# Exception when using Linq to SQL on website. There is already open data reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

On a ASP.NET website I use LINQ to SQL to get data. This operation somewhat long (can be up to 3 seconds) and often user clicks on a link second time

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first.

I looked at [DataReader already open when using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692338/datareader-already-open-when-using-linq) and other similar threads but I do not understand how to handle/fix this.

Should I get rid of LINQ to SQL alltogether? What is a proper way to handle this?

**EDIT:**

Code that I call from Page_Load

```
using (var wdc = new WebDataContext())
            {
                // Expensive operation, increase timeout
                wdc.CommandTimeout = 120;

                // First need to update data for this customer
                wdc.Web_WrkTrackShipment_Update((int)this.Parent.ProviderUserKey, sessionId);

                // Return set of this data based on parameters.
                return wdc.Web_WrkTrackShipment_Load(sessionId, pageNo, pageSize, searchCriteria, dateFrom, dateTo, ref pageCount_Null).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: The proper way to handle this is to create a small piece of code that reproduces the problem, then post that code here.

Comment: how do you handle DB connections in your project?

Comment: Please show us your code, especially related to the connection object.

Comment: Added code to show how I use context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by setting [Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to true in the connectionstring. Note that this might indicate a N+1 join problem, it really depends on the query.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" + 
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI" +
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, yhe underlying reason is DataContext not being thread-safe. Different requests run on different threads.

Don't share your DataContext between threads. Either start one on BeginRequest and close it on EndRequest - or create one locally whenever you need it, and wrap it in a `using` statement so it is immediately disposed when your code has finished using it.

Comment: Don't even create one per request, create one per transaction.  If object A has a property that is a collection of objects Bs and you delete them all and save to the database, if you use the same DataContext to get another copy of object A then it doesn't go back to the database it just gives you the same object a with a collection full of object bs.